# What is it in my .bash_profile that causes my terminal to open and shortly after read [process competed]

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, terminal

What is it in my `.bash_profile` that causes my terminal to open and shortly after read [process competed].

Here are the contents of the file:

```
#The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/usr/local/opt/libtool/libexec/gnubin:/Users/caleb/cardano-node-1.31.0-macos:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

alias bp='vi .bash_profile'
alias cdj='cd japr'
alias fire='open fireplace.mp4 && cliclick w:420 && cliclick kp:space && cliclick kd:cmd && cliclick t:f && cliclick ku:cmd && wizcon --scene_id 5 10.0.0.27 ON && wizcon --scene_id 5 10.0.0.104 ON'
alias sexy='open fireplace.mp4 && cliclick w:420 && cliclick kp:space && cliclick kd:cmd && cliclick t:f && cliclick ku:cmd && open Romance.mp3 && wizcon --scene_id 5 10.0.0.104 ON && wizcon --scene_id 5 10.0.0.27 ON'
alias party='wizcon --scene_id 4 10.0.0.104 ON && wizcon --scene_id 4 10.0.0.27 ON'
alias on='wizcon 10.0.0.104 ON && wizcon 10.0.0.27 ON'
alias off='wizcon 10.0.0.104 OFF && wizcon 10.0.0.27 OFF'
alias gn='sleep 30 && wizcon 10.0.0.104 OFF && wizcon 10.0.0.27 OFF && sudo shutdown -s'
[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && source ~/.bashrc # ghcup-env
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin/:$PATH"
```

Comment: Most likely that `[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && source ~/.bashrc # ghcup-env`.

Comment: I don't see anything here that'd cause the shell to exit. Are you sure you're running bash (recent versions of macOS default to zsh instead), and what's in ~/.bashrc?

Comment: The traditional way to solve this (when not obvious) is through process of elimination.  Comment out ALL of the lines and remove them one by one (or even divide and conquer method) until it breaks.  Then figure out why the offending line breaks.